# Организация видеосвязи на сайте

Tags: связь, видео

Добрый день. При помощи какой технологий можно организовать возможность видео звонков в пределах одного сайта? Подозреваю, что это будет Flash, но не знаю, в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если клиент не должен ничего устанавливать, то

- tokbox
- dimdim

Если можно что-то устанавливать, то поднять Jabber на своем сервере. Еще есть ConferenceXP.

И кроме того:

- Adobe Connect
- GoToMeeting

Comment: Через Jabber можно организовывать видео-связь?

Comment: Можно. Например, через расширение XMPP - Jingle. Пример - Google Talk.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 2):

На флэш относительно просто.

Это технология для прямого соединения между клиентами: [Use RTMFP for developing real-time collaboration applications](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/).

[Видео урок по ней](http://www.flashrealtime.com/tuts/p2p-in-flash.html).

[Исходники к нему и краткое описание](http://www.flashrealtime.com/basics-of-p2p-in-flash/).

(нужен флеш не ниже 10.1, и [`flash builder`](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashbuilder_burrito/)).

Если нужно через сервер - то через `Flash Media Server` или подобное.

Помните, что при использовании флеша на сайте, отпадает `iPad/iPhone`.

Comment: Всех приветствую. В продолжении разговора... А есть ли способы реализации видеоконференции и для пользователей pc и для apple (p2p)? + Например если я хочу построить видеоконференцию на сайте не прибегая к сторонним (платным) готовым программным решениям?
Просмотрев ролик предыдущего ответа (полностью удовлетворен - спасибо) захотелось теперь того же самого только и для пользователей apple. Есть ли Варианты?
Заранее очень благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Flash решение работает абсолютно одинаково и для PC (windows) и для Mac (OS X) в браузере, различий нет. 

Для iOS (Android), решений для сайтов нет, для мобильных платформ ваши задачи лучше решать построением приложения на Adobe AIR, которое работает на всех мобильных платформах.